# align horizontal divs centrally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a horizontal row of divs, all of the same width and containing some text. Ideally, I don't want to set their positions manually because it will be difficult to maintain/replicate with a different number of divs. My two approaches so far, neither of which have been satisfactory, are:
1. Use a series of divs, setting float: left in css. This way they all fall to the left, when I want them, essentially, justified so they fill the width of their container with even spacing. 
2. Use a series of spans, setting text-align: center for their parent in css. This justifies then correctly but the text inside the spans are of varying length, meaning the ones with less text are less wide than the others.

How can I combine these two properties: the ability to set the width manually as for divs, but the ability to set the position to be central as for spans with text-align. Is there a property like floating-child-align?

Comment: Have you tried equal left and right margins in the child elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the width of your spans if you give them `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I thought I had tried this, turns out I had not, or I'd done it wrong. This was all I needed. Those interested can see what I meant, with this suggestion incorporated and functional here: http://jsfiddle.net/ygaWy/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right if you calculate the margins and sizes of the divs properly. For example look at the following fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r7KMB/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.container {
    width : 230px; height:20px;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
.item {
    width: 30px; height: 15px;
    border : 1px solid red;
    margin: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping to avoid. The container width cannot be adjusted in this example without having to recalculate and adjust the margins of your "item" divs as well.